# Transferring data, for example (service_id = 1506) from a page to a new page

Tags: php, ajax, post

I need to customize the button that is located on the service page. When clicked, it should transfer the service_id to another page and open immediately.

tamplate smarty

```
<a class="menuitm menu-auto" id="gotozabbixlist" ><span>Zabbix host list</span>
                <input id="secretid" value="{php} echo $_REQUEST['id']; {/php}" type="hidden"/></a>
```

ajax

```
$('#gotozabbixlist').on('click', function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            let id = document.getElementById('secretid').value;
            let url = 'http://www.website.com/bla/bla/zabbixhost.php';
            $.ajax({
                url: url ,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    someData: id
                },
                success: function (){

                }
            });
        })
```

The file that accepts it zabbixhost.php

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);
```

I've been thinking about this for two days now.

Comment: Ajax doesn't open a page , it makes a background request. Use window.location in JS to navigate to a whole new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in a different way.
I just add "?id = 12323" to the url and then get it with "$service_id = $_REQUEST['id'];"

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is used to make a background request ... what you can do however have a submit button to the form and in the action of the form you have the route to the service page...

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.website.com/bla/bla/zabbixhost.php">
    <span>Zabbix host list</span>
    <input id="secretid" value="{php} echo $_REQUEST['id']; {/php}" type="hidden"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is that the form doesn't fit, and for some reason it doesn't go to the page when you submit it. 
So I had to do it through AJAX or something else.